# Retorno de função

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Boa tarde,

Tenho esses dois casos:

1. Tenho uma modal com `<form action="{{url_for('rota')}}"` e nessa rota eu estou dando um update nas informações, meu problema é no retorno desse POST, o que eu coloco para retornar para modal, se possível com uma mensagem de "Dados atualizados com sucesso"

   ```
   dados.con_contato = request.form.get('modalTelContato')
   dados.con_contato_observacao = request.form.get('modalRecado')

   update = con_contatos.update(dados)

   return o que eu coloco aqui???
   ```
2. Eu tenho um botão "Salvar" definido com "submit" e no meu form eu tenho um `onsubmit="return closeSelf(this);"`

Nesse script eu fiz assim:

```
function closeSelf (f) {
  f.submit();
  window.close();
}
```

Meu problema é que se eu deixo assim, ele fecha sem dar o submit, se eu tiro o window.close(), ele executa o submit mas não fecha a janela corrente!

Comment: Você tem duas questões distintas. Deve posta-las separadamente.

Comment: Outra dica: Pense com cuidado o título. Ele deve descrever o problema de forma sucinta. O seu problema não é desconhecer como se faz um retorno de função, mas como responder uma requisição HTTP.

Comment: o return não deveria ser a pagina para onde o camarada vai ser redirecionado?

Comment: @EltonNunes, sim, deveria mostrar uma mensagem de "dados alterados com sucesso" e fechava a modal.

Comment: me refiro a url_for(pagina,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o [Flash](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/flashing/), só importar pelo flask mesmo

```
from flask import Flask, flash
```

no seu código da rota você retorna essa função para a qual o html vai está pronto para receber a mensagem

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for

dados.con_contato = request.form.get('modalTelContato')
dados.con_contato_observacao = request.form.get('modalRecado')

update = con_contatos.update(dados)

flash('Dados atualizados com sucesso')
return redirect(url_for('*ROTA*'))
```

na pagina html você vai utilizar o [jinja2](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/)(obvio)
Exemplo de como você vai pegar essa mensagem dps de ter renderizado o back-end

```
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
  {% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
      {{ message }} # aqui você vai receber a mensagem que configurou lá na rota com o 'flash'
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

e ta pronto!